# iptables, after specifying an interface to drop traffic it drops all traffic of all interfaces

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, linux-networking

We have currently the situation that one interface (`eth0`) is linked to the internet. and we 2 other devices (`eth1`/`eth2`) for management purposes.

Now the idea is to block off `eth0` completely from the internet except port 443 for incoming and allow the other 2 interfaces to do their day to day trafficking.

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT  
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth2 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth2 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
```

As soon it hits the `DROP` of the `eth0`-interface, it drops the traffic of every interface (`eth1` and `eth2`).. After spending 2 days I have really NO clue what i'm doing wrong.. Port 443 is nicely open (after inspecting with `nmap`).

Comment: Post route -n output please

Comment: Peter, tnx for the suggesion.. i was using in my test enviroment the same subnet (192.168.0.0/24) changed the second interface to a different subnet and now it seems to be working. But now I seems to lost my internet connection. hereby by route -n

Comment: - Kernel IP routing table
- Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
- 192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
- 192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
- 169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
- 172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
- 0.0.0.0         192.168.0.200   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

Comment: Please edit your original question wirh the extra information, so you can have proper formatting. This is not readable in comments.